# oAuth - 3rd party app accessing my org without a connected app

Tags: integration, oauth

I'm trying to use Skyvia to integrate salesforce with third-party systems. When I create a new connection, I have the possibility of choosing OAuth as the type of authentication. But how can it work if I haven't created any connected apps? Which client id is used?

[image]
[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Connected App exists in their Production or Developer org. This Connected App is used to identify that it is indeed their app (notice the Skyvia logo on the Allow Access page). When you first allow access to the app in your org, Salesforce will automatically create a Connected App in your org that identifies this app. Administrators can use this app to choose to allow/block access by profile, view the number of active connections, etc. You will not be able to see the Client ID, as this is not your app, but the developers.